# ERROR 42703: no permite crear las tablas

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
create table proveedores (idproveedores int,rut varchar(20),nombre varchar(50),direccion varchar(30),telefono varchar(20),paginaweb varchar (30),
PRIMARY KEY(idproveedores));

create table clientes (idclientes int, rut varchar(20),nombre varchar(30),direccion varchar(40),telefono varchar(20), correo varchar(50),PRIMARY KEY
(idclientes));

create table categoria(idcategoria int, idproductoc int,nombre varchar(40),descripcion varchar(50),PRIMARY KEY(idcategoria));

create table ventas (idventas int,idproductov int,articulo varchar(50),precio varchar(50),fecha varchar(50), descuento varchar(50),
 monto_final varchar(50),PRIMARY KEY(idventas));
                     
create table detalle_ventas (id_dventas int, idproductod int,nombre_venta varchar(50), fecha_venta varchar(50),PRIMARY KEY(id_dventas));

create table productos (idproductos int,idproductoc int,idproductov int,idproductod int,nombre varchar(50),precio_actual varchar(40),stock varchar(10),
PRIMARY KEY(idproductos),FOREIGN KEY(idcategoria)REFERENCES categoria(idcategoria),FOREIGN KEY(idventas)REFERENCES ventas(idventas),
FOREIGN KEY(id_dventas)REFERENCES detalle_ventas(id_dventas));
```

Mi inquietud va por lo que me salta el error de que no tengo referida la columna `idcategoria` cuando ya verificado y en la creación de la tabla veo la columna ahí.

No entiendo por qué no me es posible realizar la creación si todo aparentemente está bien.

Al tratar de ejecutar el código me sale el error que se ve en la imagen:

[image: Captura de pantalla del mensaje de error]

Comment: Pero, no has creado el campo `idcategoria` en la tabla `productos`, ¿cómo quieres que se referencie un campo que no existe en la tabla de origen?

Answer (score 0):

Para poder crear una relación entre tablas es necesario que el campo esté creado en la tabla de origen:

```
FOREIGN KEY(idcategoria) REFERENCES categoria(idcategoria),
```

En este caso estás solicitando que el campo `idcategoria` de la tabla actual esté relacionado con el campo `idcategoria` de la tabla `categoria`.

Has comprobado la existencia del campo `idcategoria` de la tabla `categoria`, pero has olvidado crear el campo en la tabla que estás definiendo.

Un ejemplo para hacerlo correctamente (incluyendo dos campos más que te faltan) podría ser el siguiente:

```
CREATE TABLE productos (
    idproductos int,
    idproductoc int,
    idproductov int,
    idproductod int,
    nombre varchar(50),
    precio_actual varchar(40),
    stock varchar(10),
    idcategoria int, -- Primera referencia
    id_dventas int, -- Segunda referecia
    idventas int, -- Tercera referencia
    PRIMARY KEY(idproductos),
    FOREIGN KEY(idcategoria) REFERENCES categoria(idcategoria),
    FOREIGN KEY(idventas) REFERENCES ventas(idventas),
    FOREIGN KEY(id_dventas) REFERENCES detalle_ventas(id_dventas)
);
```